# How can I install the latest upstream version of ImageMagick without compiling?

Tags: package-management, imagemagick

I had some issues with ImageMagick and I was told Ubuntu's default ImageMagick package is an *ancient version* and I should upgrade to resolve my issues.

How can I do that? I have the latest Ubuntu version (12.10). Synaptic shows me `8:6.7.7.10-2ubuntu4` as the latest version of IM. It means my IM version is `6.7.7.10` (`convert --version` outputs the same). IM [does not provide deb binaries](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/binary-releases.html#unix) itself. Debian [has something newer](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=imagemagick), but in some testing/experimental branches if I understand it well. I found [IM on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick), but there are no instructions how to add this to my sources, it seems it is not one of the usual PPAs I meet when searching for the latest/beta software. I don't know how to work with this one.

Is there a way how to mark a package to be taken from some *bleeding edge* sources and leave the rest of my system to be taken from standard sources? It would be probably the best to upgrade to the last stable version of IM (`6.8`), but that is probably sci-fi as it is not even in Debian. However, I need at least `6.7.9`.

---

**Note:** I want to avoid compilation from source. I hate having installed something and not being able to manipulate with it easily with `apt-get` or Synaptic. Moreover, there are no updates for compiled programs. Always I compile I feel like going against the system, like using glue, wires and duck tape. No, I do not want to compile it for sure.

Comment: The easiest way to get new versions is to actually help out with packaging the new version and uploading it for the maintainers. Suggest join the https://launchpad.net/imagemagick team or preferably work upstream.

Comment: That would be nice, but I am Python developer with absolutely no deeper knowledge of Ubuntu/Debian packaging, so it is task rather for people who are closer to DevOps/packaging/UNIX managment. I will help the world by writing open source Python libraries :)

Comment: There isnt really an answer as far as I can see other than by compiling & packaging hence the suggestion.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to compile, but this may be of interest: You can keep your existing `imagemagick` package and its dependencies with this method. You can run configure with `--prefix=/opt`, compile the program, and then install to `/opt` with `checkinstall`, so you can manage the compiled version as a package via `apt-get`. If you want to use the new version, you have to specify  `/opt/bin/convert` when say you run `convert`, unless you create some symlinks. Either way, you can keep both the standard package version and your compiled version

Comment: Well, I did not know about `checkinstall`. If I understand it right, it should install compiled version of program into my system and then represent it as a package in Synaptic or so, which means I can safely and easily remove it later. That would be great!

Comment: I just tried `checkinstall` and it worked. I can see the package in Synaptic. If you suggest it in proper answer, I will accept it. It solved my problem and bridged my aversion to compiling.

Comment: I've done an answer using `checkinstall`: it should be just what you wanted. `checkinstall` is a very useful program: I use it all the time.

Comment: Wow, for the "user friendly" Linux, this seems a lot harder to do than on the "bare metal" distributions!!

Arch: `yaourt -S imagemagick-svn` for the latest version from source and the package manager will update/rebuild it for you when needed :D

Comment: The outdated ImageMagick package has been reported as a bug in Ubuntu: [Bug #1179054 "Update to 6.8"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1179054) Go the link above and click "This bug affects me" Hopefully soon the ImageMagick package will be updated and you can install the latest version with apt-get.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Please Note:** Even though [Honza](https://askubuntu.com/users/34304/honza-javorek) initially said that he did not want to compile, we discussed using `checkinstall` to install the compiled package in the comments above. That was just what [Honza](https://askubuntu.com/users/34304/honza-javorek) wanted, as programs installed with `checkinstall` can be removed like any other package with the package manager.

---

As we are installing to `/opt` using `checkinstall` after the build, we can leave the original `imagemagick` package in place. (Infact, install the repository version if it is not already installed.) The dependencies can be left installed, and they are no different for the most recent version of `imagemagick`. What we need to do is install the build dependencies and some other tools first of all:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall && sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick
```

Download the source code from [the official site](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) and, using terminal, `cd` to where the source package is and extract it:

```
tar -xzvf ImageMagick-6.8.3-9.tar.gz
```

Now move to that folder with

```
cd Imagemagick-6.8.3-9
```

Now, if you want to find out the available options for the build, run

```
./configure --help
```

However, mostly everything is already set to `enabled`, so there is little need to specify anything further, apart from the necessary `--prefix`. You could use other locations, but we shall use `/opt` here. Now run `configure` and `make`:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/imagemagick-6.8 && make
```

Now, the last thing to do is to use `checkinstall` to install the package. Make sure you are in the `Imagemagick-6.8.3-9` folder and run

```
sudo checkinstall
```

You can of course run `checkinstall` with parameters such as `--pkgversion=` or choose them after you have run `sudo checkinstall`, but all the defaults are fine here. The package name that will be created will be called `imagemagick-6.8.3-9` and it will be installed in `/opt/imagemagick-6.8`.

You will now be also able to see the package in `Synaptic` and manage it just like any other packages, and removing it will not cause problems with other packages.

If you want to run your new versions, you will need to use `/opt/imagemagick-6.8/convert`, for example, as `/opt` is not in `$PATH`, and just running `convert` will call the repo version. You could create some symlinks if you wanted to always run the `/opt` version of the programs.

**Please note** that this is what [Honza](https://askubuntu.com/users/34304/honza-javorek) wanted, even though he initially was averse to compiling, until `checkinstall` was discussed.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, my question was originally just "How can I install current the latest upstream version of ImageMagick", the "without compiling" part was added by [fossfreedom](http://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) moderator, probably after reading my note at the end of my question.

Comment: Proper path to ``convert`` is ``/opt/imagemagick-6.x/bin/convert``. At least it is that way for 6.9.1 version which I installed now. Your path is missing ``/bin/``.

Comment: I got the following error when trying to install the build dependencies: `Unable to find a source package for imagemagick`. I was able to install dependencies this way: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagick++-dev` as detailed [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20814).

Comment: Another reason you might see ````Unable to find a source package for imagemagick```` is you need to uncomment deb-src sources in /etc/apt/source.list so that package is found.

Comment: Note, I had to do `ldconfig` after `checkinstall` to get the bindings updated.

Comment: Are there additional steps necessary to make php-imagick also use the new version?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can get an AppImage for ImageMagick ([here](https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/magick)). You only need to mark the file as executable, with `chmod +x magick`, for instance, and then put the file in some folder belonging to your PATH (issue the comand `echo $PATH` valid folders). I usually put these files under `$HOME/.local/bin`.

Of course, these operations can also be done via graphical utilities such as Nautilus, if you do not want to use the terminal.

With this approach, you're effectively "installing without compiling". Please note that you must have FUSE and libc (which is already the case in many Linux distributions).

Assuming you have wget, you can use these commands:

```
cd ~
wget https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/binaries/magick
chmod +x magick
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
mv magick ~/.local/bin
```