# How are the chances that ImageMagick 7 will be part of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: imagemagick, 20.04

I tried to find issues for the Upgrade in Ubuntu 20.04 to ImageMagick 7, but did not find one.

I believe the Package will be imported from Debian which also seems to be still on ImageMagick 6.9 ?

Should an upgrade request first be made at Debian side?

Comment: Questions on not supported versions (including development versions) are off topic here.

Comment: But see https://askubuntu.com/q/267746/248158 if you really want a more recent version in 20.04. The answer there provides elaborate instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Debian Package Tracker for Imagemagick](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/imagemagick) to see some of the issues.

- The automated version monitoring tool does not yet (as of today) register 7.0 as being available. So nobody at Debian knows to package it.
- Take a look at the many HIGH and NORMAL issues in the "Action Needed" section. A lot of volunteer effort is needed before another version can be packaged at all!

So I would evaluate the chances of Imagemagick 7 making it into Ubuntu 20.04 as LOW.

It's possible if a group of Debian-skilled volunteers charge in and help the current maintainers work all those problems and package 7.0.9 immediately...it's just not likely that such a group is about to do that.

If you want to move the ball forward, join the Imagemagick Maintainers Team.